# Bug in integrate MySQL function JSON_SEARCH

Tags: mysql, sql, json, search, mariadb

how i use MySQL function JSON_SEARCH on all values, not only on strings?

All this bug is documented on MySQL emulator: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2UdrxqrQ3DeonbKWw3pVVp/0

I have DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    json_config JSON,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO table_name (id,json_config)
VALUES 
  (NULL, '{
    "_id": "60111111111111175b78fe2fa",
    "intestx": 0,
    "codes": [
        48348,
        28923,
        39080
   ],
   "test": 562222222222456
   }');
```

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_SEARCH(json_config, 'all', '%1111%')
FROM table_name;
```

Result #1:

```
"$._id" #this is OK
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_SEARCH(json_config, 'all', '%2222%')
FROM table_name;
```

Result #2:

```
null # this is bad BUG, because is exist match with $.test
```

**Thank you for your advice on how to search over all values, not only on the string, but also over numbers, etc.**

EDIT: I found this bug report on MySQL bugzilla since 2015, but this bug has not been resolved, only update on documentation about function search only on strings... :-D https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233

**MySQL probably can't search correctly, only over strings. So I probably can't solve it via SQL (view), but I have to solve it by complex programming of my own logic in the form of PHP + SQL (table)...**

*I'm not happy about that at all. If you knew any handy PHP component that could do this. By that I mean parse JSON to key, value combinations to create all combinations of list of variables.*

Comment: Making the `"test"` value a string, instead of a number, then [it works](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2UdrxqrQ3DeonbKWw3pVVp/1) I didn't see anything specific about that in the docs, so I'm not sure what the situation might be?

Comment: @PaulT. However, in my example I state that the string works. However, I'm looking for value, in which case it doesn't work. Maybe it would somehow specify the delimiter. I Cannot convert all numbers to strings, but this is bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is only in MySQL. I installed MariaDB and it works properly for me there. So I will use MariaDB and that solves it for me.

EDIT: I cannot make solved flat to own answear... :-) But this is solved for me.